# How to show the error message if any of the char string is removed from password field using xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have created two input fields which is username and password in `XAML`.

For example, I'm giving you the password like `App@1234` in password field and If I remove any of the character string like(@,A,1) from the password field then the error should occur in label.

Here is `XAML` code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginUser"
             x:Class="LoginUser.MainPage">
  <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
    <Entry x:Name="txtUsername"  Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
    <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True">
      <Entry.Behaviors>
        <local:ValidationBehavior x:Name="passwordValidator"/>
      </Entry.Behaviors>
    </Entry>
    <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="Button_Onclick"></Button>
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the `HandleTextChanged` event cs file code:

```
public class ValidationBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
{
    const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*$";

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnAttachedTo(bindable);
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        bool IsValid = false;
        IsValid = (Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsValid ? Color.Default : Color.Red;
        Label errorLabel = ((Entry)sender).FindByName<Label>("errorMessage");
        if (IsValid)
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Please enter the correct password";
        }
        else
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "";
        }
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
        base.OnDetachingFrom(bindable);
    }
}
```

Comment: you have asked some variation of this question **5 times** in the past 2 days.  Please stop reposting the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Jason says is true, maybe you should have just asked one question only.
So that's the last answer I give you.

First: Add a `Label` below your `Entry` like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginUser"
         x:Class="LoginUser.MainPage">
<StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50" VerticalOptions="Center">
   <Entry x:Name="txtUsername"  Placeholder="Username"></Entry>
   <Entry x:Name="txtPassword" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True">
     <Entry.Behaviors>
       <local:ValidationBehavior x:Name="passwordValidator"/>
     </Entry.Behaviors>
    <Label Text="Your message for error" IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference passwordValidator}, Path=IsInvalid}" TextColor="Red" FontSize="Micro"/>
   </Entry>
   <Button Text="Log In" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="##ff77D065" Clicked="Button_Onclick"></Button>
 </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Second: Try to get your ValidationBehavior class to be this way, your ValidationBehavior is too bad:

```cs
public class ValidationBehavior: Behavior<Entry>
{
    const string pwRegex = @"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[^\da-zA-Z]).{8,15}$";

    static readonly BindablePropertyKey IsInvalidPropertyKey = BindableProperty.CreateReadOnly("IsInvalid", typeof(bool), typeof(EmailValidatorBehavior), false);

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsInvalidProperty = IsInvalidPropertyKey.BindableProperty;

    public bool IsInvalid
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(IsInvalidProperty); }
        private set { base.SetValue(IsInvalidPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttachedTo(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged += HandleTextChanged;
    }

    void HandleTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsInvalid = !(Regex.IsMatch(e.NewTextValue, pwRegex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)));
        ((Entry)sender).TextColor = IsInvalid ? Color.Red : Color.Default;
    }

    protected override void OnDetachingFrom(Entry bindable)
    {
        bindable.TextChanged -= HandleTextChanged;
    }
}
```

> Plsssssss note that I've changed the `IsValid` property to `**IsInvalid**` so this is more logical

I hope this will help you finally and not see more duplicate questions.